# Joining Multiple tables Using Inner Join MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

so im trying to create a query in Mysql that takes multiple information from multiple tables using `inner join`, however, i am unable to make it work. Basically, i want to find out how many combatants are in each division and display the CO name, Division name and FOB. For this assignment, i assume each CO is in charge of one division and everything within the division, and each regiment has the same FOB as its Brigade, so, i would have to combine the 3 tables to get my resulting query. My tables are below:

ArmyRegiment Table:

```
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+
| Name                                        | Codename            | Type                 | FOB            | Combatants |
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+
| 12 RÃ©giment blindÃ© du Canada              | Adsum               | Armour               | CFB Valcartier |          9 |
| 5 RÃ©giment d'artillerie lÃ©gÃ¨re du Canada | Ubique              | Artillery            | CFB Valcartier |         12 |
| 5 Combat Engineer Regiment                  |                     | Support              | CFB Valcartier |          5 |
| 3rd Battalion, Royal 22e RÃ©giment          | VipÃ¨re             | Light Infantry       | CFB Valcartier |          5 |
| The Canadian Grenadier Guards               |                     | Light Infantry       | Montreal       |          5 |
| Les Fusiliers Mont-Royal                    |                     | Light Infantry       | Montreal       |          7 |
| The Royal Canadian Hussars                  | Red Bird            | Reconnaissance       | Montreal       |         10 |
| Royal Canadian Horse Artillery              | Thunder             | Artillery            | CFB Edmonton   |         10 |
| Lord Strathcona's Horse                     | Strat               | Armour               | CFB Edmonton   |         15 |
| 1 Service Battalion                         | Angel 1             | Combat Service Suppo | CFB Edmonton   |          5 |
| The Saskatchewan Dragoons                   | Dragoon             | Armour Reconnaissanc | Winnipeg       |          8 |
| The Royal Winnipeg Rifles                   | Little Black Devils | Light Infantry       | Winnipeg       |          5 |
| 38 Service Battalion                        | Little Black Devils | Combat Servicee Supp | Winnipeg       |         10 |
| 20th Field Artillery Regiment               |                     | Artillery            | Calgary        |         11 |
| 41 Combat Engineer Regiment                 |                     | Support              | Calgary        |          5 |
| 1st Battalion, The Royal Canadian Reg       | Royal Canadians     | Mechanized infantry  | CFB Petawawa   |          6 |
| 2 Combat Engineer Regiment                  | Burner              | Support              | CFB Petawawa   |          5 |
| The Royal Highland Fusiliers of Canada      | Highland Laddies    | Light Infantry       | London         |          7 |
| The Royal London Light Infantry             | The Rileys          | Light Infantry       | London         |          6 |
| The Governor General's Horse Guards         | Gugga Huggas        | Reconnaissance       | Toronto        |          6 |
| The Queen's Own Rifles of Canada            |                     | Airborne Light Infan | Toronto        |         10 |
| 48th Highlanders of Canada                  |                     | Light Infantry       | Toronto        |          5 |
| 84th Independent Field Battery              |                     | Artillery            | Halifax        |          6 |
| 36 Combat Engineer Regiment                 | Red Clovers         | Support              | Halifax        |          5 |
| The West Nova Scotia Regiment               |                     | Light Infantry       | Halifax        |          6 |
| The Royal New Brunswick Regiment            | Rider               | Light Infantry       | Moncton        |          6 |
| 37 Combat Engineer Regiment                 |                     | Support              | Moncton        |          8 |
| 8th Canadian Hussars                        | The Crazy Eights    | Reconnaissance       | Moncton        |         10 |
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------+------------+
```

ArmyBrigade Table:

```
+---------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
| Name                                  | CO                     | FOB            |
+---------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
| 36th Canadian Brigade Group           | MGen B.M. Hoffmeister  | Halifax        |
| 37th Canadian Brigade Group           | MGen B.M. Hoffmeister  | Moncton        |
| 2nd Canadian Mechanized Brigade Group | Gen George Kitching    | CFB Petawawa   |
| 31 Canadian Brigade Group             | Gen George Kitching    | London         |
| 32 Canadian Brigade Group             | Gen George Kitching    | Toronto        |
| 1st Canadian Mechanized Brigade Group | Brigadier-Gen W.D Eyre | CFB Edmonton   |
| 38 Canadian Brigade Group             | Brigadier-Gen W.D Eyre | Winnipeg       |
| 41 Canadian Brigade Group             | Brigadier-Gen W.D Eyre | Calgary        |
| 5th Canadian Mechanized Brigade Group | MGen Sam Steeles       | CFB Valcartier |
| 34 Canadian Brigade Group             | MGen Sam Steeles       | Montreal       |
+---------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

ArmyDivision Table:

```
+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| Name                  | CO                     | FOB          |
+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 3rd Canadian Division | Brigadier-Gen W.D Eyre |              |
| 2nd Canadian Division | MGen Sam Steeles       | Quebec       |
| 1st Canadian Division | MGen Dean Milner       | CFB Kingston |
| 4th Canadian Division | Gen George Kitching    | Ontario      |
| 5th Canadian Division | MGen B.M. Hoffmeister  |              |
+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------+
```

And this is the code i have been trying to make work with which is what i have learned to do (simpler version though):

```
select sum(r.combatants) Personal, b.CO, r.FOB from ArmyRegiment r, ArmyBrigade b where b.FOB=r.FOB group by b.CO join inner ArmyDivison d on d.CO = ArmyBrigade.CO;
```

but i get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join inner ArmyDivison d on d.CO = ArmyBrigade.CO' at line 1
```

Comment: Join goes before the where and group by.....

Comment: doesnt work, i still get the same error

Comment: Don't mix the old-school comma syntax for a join operation with the newer JOIN keyword. (The commas between the tables in the FROM clause are equivalent to `JOIN` keyword... if you want to join an additional table, that needs to come *before* the WHERE clause. `SELECT ... FROM a JOIN b JOIN c WHERE ...`. For inner joins, the join predicates can be either in an ON clause or in the WHERE clause. If you want to join to the result of a query, wrap the query in parens, and use the query in place of a table name.

Comment: @spencer7593 ok; how would u warp the query so that i can use it instead of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of valid syntax for joining three tables, based on the tables and columns referenced in the query syntax in the question...

Assuming that `FOB` column is unique in `ArmyBrigade`, and `CO` column is unique in `ArmyDivision`,

```
SELECT d.CO                        AS ArmyDivision_CO
     , d.FOB                       AS ArmyDivision_FOB
     , IFNULL(SUM(r.combatants),0) AS total_combatants
  FROM ArmyDivision d
  LEFT
  JOIN ArmyBrigade b
    ON b.CO = d.CO
  LEFT
  JOIN ArmyRegiment r
    ON r.FOB = b.FOB
 GROUP BY d.CO, d.FOB
```

Given the sample data, we expect this to return a resultset like this:

```
+------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| ArmyDivision_CO        | ArmyDivision_FOB | total_combatants |
+------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Brigadier-Gen W.D Eyre |                  |                  |
| Gen George Kitching    | Ontario          |                  |
| MGen B.M. Hoffmeister  |                  |                  |
| MGen Dean Milner       | CFB Kingston     |                  |
| MGen Sam Steeles       | Quebec           |                  |
+------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Note that this returns the total of combatants for each row in ArmyDivision, but if there are any rows in ArmyRegiment that do not match a row in ArmyBrigade, or any rows in ArmyBrigade that do not match a row in ArmyDivision, then the those unmatched rows will not be included in total_combatants.

Comment: Thank you so much, i modified it a bit to include some more info, but it works so thank you.